# Error make GMP - undefined reference

Tags: mingw, undefined-reference, gmp

I am working on a project in C++ where I need to use GMP. I have installed MinGW 6.1.0. From MSYS, I tried:

---

./configure --prefix=C:\gmp --enable-cxx

make

make check

---

I then get the following errors:

---

```
make[5]: Leaving directory `/C/Users/Admin/Downloads/gmp-6.1.2.tar/gmp-6.1.2/tests/misc'
```

make[4]: Leaving directory `/C/Users/Admin/Downloads/gmp-6.1.2.tar/gmp-6.1.2/tests/misc'
make[3]: Leaving directory`/C/Users/Admin/Downloads/gmp-6.1.2.tar/gmp-6.1.2/tests/misc'
Making check in cxx
make[3]: Entering directory `/C/Users/Admin/Downloads/gmp-6.1.2.tar/gmp-6.1.2/tests/cxx'
make  t-binary.exe t-cast.exe t-cxx11.exe t-headers.exe t-iostream.exe t-istream.exe t-locale.exe t-misc.exe t-mix.exe t-ops.exe t-ops2.exe t-ops3.exe t-ostream.exe t-prec.exe t-ternary.exe t-unary.exe t-do-exceptions-work-at-all-with-this-compiler.exe t-assign.exe t-constr.exe t-rand.exe
make[4]: Entering directory`/C/Users/Admin/Downloads/gmp-6.1.2.tar/gmp-6.1.2/tests/cxx'
make[4]: `t-binary.exe' is up to date.
make[4]:`t-cast.exe' is up to date.
make[4]: `t-cxx11.exe' is up to date.
make[4]:`t-headers.exe' is up to date.
make[4]: `t-iostream.exe' is up to date.
make[4]:`t-istream.exe' is up to date.
make[4]: `t-locale.exe' is up to date.
make[4]:`t-misc.exe' is up to date.
make[4]: `t-mix.exe' is up to date.
make[4]:`t-ops.exe' is up to date.
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link /mingw/bin/g++.exe  -DWINVER=0x0501 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0501 -O2 -pipe -mms-bitfields -fno-builtin -march=i686 -mtune=i686  -L/mingw/lib -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--export-all-symbols -o t-ops2.exe t-ops2.o -L../../.libs ../../tests/libtests.la ../../libgmpxx.la ../../libgmp.la -lm
libtool: link: /mingw/bin/g++.exe -DWINVER=0x0501 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_WIN32_IE=0x0501 -O2 -pipe -mms-bitfields -fno-builtin -march=i686 -mtune=i686 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--export-all-symbols -o t-ops2.exe t-ops2.o  -L/mingw/lib -L../../.libs ../../tests/.libs/libtests.a ../../.libs/libgmpxx.a /c/Users/Admin/Downloads/gmp-6.1.2.tar/gmp-6.1.2/.libs/libgmp.a ../../.libs/libgmp.a
../../tests/.libs/libtests.a(misc.o):misc.c:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `_impure_ptr'
../../tests/.libs/libtests.a(misc.o):misc.c:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to`_impure_ptr'
../../tests/.libs/libtests.a(misc.o):misc.c:(.text+0x158): undefined reference to `_impure_ptr'
../../tests/.libs/libtests.a(misc.o):misc.c:(.text+0x180): undefined reference to`_impure_ptr'
../../tests/.libs/libtests.a(misc.o):misc.c:(.text+0x1a8): undefined reference to `_impure_ptr'
../../tests/.libs/libtests.a(misc.o):misc.c:(.text+0x1c4): more undefined references to`_impure_ptr' follow
../../tests/.libs/libtests.a(misc.o):misc.c:(.text+0x316): undefined reference to `_imp___ctype_'
../../tests/.libs/libtests.a(misc.o):misc.c:(.text+0x4e8): undefined reference to`_impure_ptr'
../../tests/.libs/libtests.a(misc.o):misc.c:(.text+0x510): undefined reference to `_impure_ptr'
../../tests/.libs/libtests.a(misc.o):misc.c:(.text+0x52c): undefined reference to`_impure_ptr'
../../tests/.libs/libtests.a(misc.o):misc.c:(.text+0x588): undefined reference to `_impure_ptr'
../../tests/.libs/libtests.a(misc.o):misc.c:(.text+0x5b0): undefined reference to`_impure_ptr'
../../tests/.libs/libtests.a(misc.o):misc.c:(.text+0x5cc): more undefined references to `_impure_ptr' follow
c:/Users/Admin/Downloads/gmp-6.1.2.tar/gmp-6.1.2/.libs/libgmp.a(set_str.o):set_str.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to`_imp___ctype_'
c:/Users/Admin/Downloads/gmp-6.1.2.tar/gmp-6.1.2/.libs/libgmp.a(set_str.o):set_str.c:(.text+0x164): undefined reference to `_imp___ctype_'
c:/Users/Admin/Downloads/gmp-6.1.2.tar/gmp-6.1.2/.libs/libgmp.a(realloc.o):realloc.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to`_impure_ptr'
c:/Users/Admin/Downloads/gmp-6.1.2.tar/gmp-6.1.2/.libs/libgmp.a(lt43-set_str.o):set_str.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `_imp___ctype_'
c:/Users/Admin/Downloads/gmp-6.1.2.tar/gmp-6.1.2/.libs/libgmp.a(lt43-set_str.o):set_str.c:(.text+0x153): undefined reference to`_imp___ctype_'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [t-ops2.exe] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/C/Users/Admin/Downloads/gmp-6.1.2.tar/gmp-6.1.2/tests/cxx'
make[3]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory`/C/Users/Admin/Downloads/gmp-6.1.2.tar/gmp-6.1.2/tests/cxx'
make[2]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/C/Users/Admin/Downloads/gmp-6.1.2.tar/gmp-6.1.2/tests'
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/C/Users/Admin/Downloads/gmp-6.1.2.tar/gmp-6.1.2'
make: *** [check] Error 2

---

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

EDIT: The version of GMP I downloaded is GMP 6.1.2

Comment: Please always include the command line that leads to the errors (i.e. include a few more lines above those you have already pasted here). Doesn't msys have a GMP package?

Comment: I just edited the code to add the lines before the errors.
If MSYS has a GMP package, how can I use it?

Comment: MSYS does have a GMP package, thank you!